# flutter two objects listview.builder Scroll up ERROR- returned an old or invalid state instance

Tags: flutter, dart

these are my projects files:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/object1form.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/object2form.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AddScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class Object1 {
  String name;
  String count;
  String units;
  Object1({this.name = '', this.count = '', this.units = ''});
}

class Object2 {
  int objectNumber;
  String name;
  Object2(int i){this.objectNumber = i; this.name = '';}
}


class AddScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddScreenState createState() => _AddScreenState();
}

class _AddScreenState extends State<AddScreen> {
  List<Object1Form> object1List = [];
  List<Object2Form> object2List = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: new Theme(
            data: new ThemeData(
              primaryColorDark: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
              //---------------------object1-------------
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 10000, minHeight: 0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    if (i == object1List.length) {
                      return Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: RaisedButton.icon(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                          ),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          label: Text("Add object1"),
                          onPressed: onAddObject1,
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return object1List[i];
                  },
                  itemCount: object1List.length + 1,
                ),
              ),
              //-----------------object2----------------------
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 10000, minHeight: 0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    if (i == object2List.length) {
                      return Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: RaisedButton.icon(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                          ),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          label: Text("Add object2"),
                          onPressed: (){onAddObject2(object2List.length+1);},
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return object2List[i];
                  },
                  itemCount: object2List.length + 1,
                ),
              ),
              //--------------------------------------------------
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }

  ///on form user deleted
  void onDeleteObject1(Object1 _object1) {
    setState(() {
      var find = object1List.firstWhere(
            (it) => it.object1 == _object1,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (find != null) object1List.removeAt(object1List.indexOf(find));
    });
  }

  ///on add form
  void onAddObject1() {
    setState(() {
      var _object1 = Object1();
      object1List.add(Object1Form(
        key: GlobalKey<FormState>(),
        object1: _object1,
        onDelete: () => onDeleteObject1(_object1),
      ));
    });
  }

  ///on form user deleted
  void onDeleteObject2(Object2 _object2) {
    setState(() {
      var find = object2List.firstWhere(
            (it) => it.object2 == _object2,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (find != null) object2List.removeAt(object2List.indexOf(find));
      for(int j = 0; j< object2List.length; j++){
        object2List[j].object2.objectNumber=j+1;
      }
    });
  }

  ///on add form
  void onAddObject2(int i) {
    setState(() {
      var _object2 = Object2(i);
      object2List.add(Object2Form(
        key: GlobalKey<FormState>(),
        object2: _object2,
        onDeleteObject2: () => onDeleteObject2(_object2),
      ));
    });
  }
}
```

object1form.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/main.dart';

typedef OnDelete();

class Object1Form extends StatefulWidget {
  final Object1 object1;
  final OnDelete onDelete;
  final state = new _Object1FormState();
  Object1Form({Key key, this.object1, this.onDelete}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Object1FormState createState() => state;
  bool isValid() => state.validate();
}

class _Object1FormState extends State<Object1Form> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> _units = <String>['', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'];
  String _unit = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final halfMediaWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 1,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Colors.white70,
          child: new Theme(
              data: new ThemeData(
                primaryColorDark: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: halfMediaWidth * 0.8,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 16, right: 16, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    onSaved: (val) => widget.object1.name = val,
                                    validator: (val) => val.length > 3
                                        ? null
                                        : 'invalid',
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Name',
                                      hintText: 'Enter Name',
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                        borderSide:
                                        new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                      ),
                                      isDense: true,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: halfMediaWidth * 0.1,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  onPressed: widget.onDelete,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                width: halfMediaWidth * 0.3,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 16, right: 5, bottom: 10),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    onSaved: (val) =>
                                    widget.object1.count = val,
                                    validator: (input) {
                                      final isDigitsOnly = int.tryParse(input);
                                      return isDigitsOnly == null
                                          ? 'Input needs to be digits only'
                                          : null;
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Count',
                                      hintText: 'Enter Count',
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                        borderSide:
                                        new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )),
                            Container(
                                width: halfMediaWidth * 0.6,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 2),
                                  child: new FormField(
                                    builder: (FormFieldState state) {
                                      return InputDecorator(
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Unit',
                                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                            new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                            borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.blue),
                                          ),
                                          isDense: true,
                                        ),
                                        isEmpty: _unit == '',
                                        child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                          child: new DropdownButton(
                                            value: _unit,
                                            isDense: true,
                                            onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                widget.object1.units = newValue;
                                                _unit = newValue;
                                                state.didChange(newValue);
                                              });
                                            },
                                            items: _units.map((String value) {
                                              return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                                value: value,
                                                child: new Text(value),
                                              );
                                            }).toList(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ]))),
        ));
  }

  ///form validator
  bool validate() {
    var valid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    if (valid) _formKey.currentState.save();
    return valid;
  }
}
```

object2form.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/main.dart';

typedef OnDeleteObject2();

class Object2Form extends StatefulWidget {
  final Object2 object2;
  final OnDeleteObject2 onDeleteObject2;
  final state = new _Object2FormState();
  Object2Form({Key key, this.object2, this.onDeleteObject2}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Object2FormState createState() => state;
  bool isValid2() => state.validateObject2();
}

class _Object2FormState extends State<Object2Form> {
  final _form2 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final halfMediaWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    int objectNumber = widget.object2.objectNumber;
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 1,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Colors.white70,
          child: new Theme(
              data: new ThemeData(
                primaryColorDark: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Form(
                  key: _form2,
                  child:
                  Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: halfMediaWidth * 0.8,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 16, right: 16, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    onSaved: (val) => widget.object2.name = val,
                                    validator: (val) => val.length > 3
                                        ? null
                                        : 'invalid',
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'name',
                                      hintText: 'Enter name',
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                        borderSide:
                                        new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                      ),
                                      isDense: true,
                                    ),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                    maxLines: 10,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Column(children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  width: halfMediaWidth * 0.1,
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                    onPressed: widget.onDeleteObject2,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      width: 30,
                                      height: 30,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child:
                                        Text('$objectNumber', style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20)),),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(200),
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ])
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ]))),
        ));
  }

  ///form validator
  bool validateObject2() {
    var valid = _form2.currentState.validate();
    if (valid) _form2.currentState.save();
    return valid;
  }
}
```

i build an app with two dynamic lists.
when i add objects to the two lists and scroll up i get this error:

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener:
The createState function for Object1Form-[LabeledGlobalKey#c1dbd] returned an old or invalid state instance: Object1Form-[LabeledGlobalKey#c1dbd], which is not null, violating the contract for createState.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart':
Failed assertion: line 4324 pos 7: '_state._widget == null'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

## 2 new StatefulElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4324:7)

## 3 StatefulWidget.createElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:809:38)

## 4 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3189:40)

## 5 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)

## 6 SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)

...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (3) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (4) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (5) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2416 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (6) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: scrollOffsetCorrection
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (7) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: debugAssertIsValid()
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (8) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6e3f7 relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///C:/Users/itay1/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:57:33
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: no effort was put into this question. try to make a minimal example and phrase a specific question so people know how to help you.

Comment: i dont know what is the problem with my code. i did minimize the code as much as i could.. you need to run it that is why i added the code. when i add object with the plus buttons and scroll up the app crash

Comment: Error is telling you exactly what is wrong with. You have to create a new state in createState(). not reuse the variable.
Have a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget/createState.html

Comment: ok so what should i changed in the code? because if i delete the state variable i cannot validate the forms

Answer (score 0):

Change these two:

1. _Object1FormState createState() => state; to _Object1FormState createState() => _Object1FormState;
2. _Object2FormState createState() => state; to _Object2FormState createState() => _Object2FormState();